# Running script only prints script source code!@#$%

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

This is weird to me. Running a script will only output its source code. Here is an MRE. Naturally, the problem is on a much larger script as well. What kind of crazy am I going to?

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\junk.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$S
)
{
    Write-Host $S
}
PS C:\src\t> .\junk.ps1 -S 'now'

    Write-Host $S

PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.1
```

Comment: Your script is returning a _script block_, if you didn't mean to, then just remove the curly braces surrounding `Write-Host`

Comment: Why is it returning a scriptblock and not the value in $S?

Comment: your script is doing this `end { { Write-Host $S } }` basically, I think you didn't see the braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` braces in your script defines a *script block literal* - an anonymous function that can be invoked later.

Remove the curly braces and the `Write-Host` statement will work:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$S
)

Write-Host $S
```

Comment: Many thanks. I got a little too brace-happy.